# Dialog Fragment does not working?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Iam getting runtime error at Dialog fragment. At the Runtime of program works smoothly but when it comes to dialog appearence imes the program crashes........... Somebody show me where did the mistake I can't resolve my problem.

### [I am posting a LogCat Image because of body limit is crossed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnyMB.png)

### MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String GUESSES = "settings_numberOfGuesses";
    public static final String ANIMALS_TYPE = "settings_animalType";
    public static final String QUIZ_BACKGROUND_COLOR = "settings_quiz_background_color";
    public static final String QUIZ_FONT = "settings_quiz_font";

    private boolean isSettingsChanged = false;

    static Typeface azkiaDemo;
    static Typeface chunkFive;
    static Typeface fontleroyBrown;
    static Typeface hauntedEyes;
    static Typeface knightBrushDemo;
    static Typeface wonderbarDemo;

    MainActivityFragment myAnimalQuizFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        azkiaDemo = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Azkia demo.otf");
        chunkFive = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Chunkfive.otf");
        fontleroyBrown = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/FontleroyBrown.ttf");
        hauntedEyes = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Haunted Eyes.otf");
        knightBrushDemo = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Knight Brush Demo.otf");
        wonderbarDemo = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Wonderbar Demo.otf");

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.quiz_preferences, false);

        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).
                registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(settingsChangedListener);

        myAnimalQuizFragment = (MainActivityFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.animalQuizFragment);


        myAnimalQuizFragment.modifyAnimalGuessRows(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
        myAnimalQuizFragment.modifyTypeofAnimals(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
        myAnimalQuizFragment.modifyQuizFont(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
        myAnimalQuizFragment.modifyBackgroundColor(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
        myAnimalQuizFragment.resetAnimalQuiz();
        isSettingsChanged = false;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        Intent preferencesIntent = new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(preferencesIntent);


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener settingsChangedListener =
            new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

                    isSettingsChanged = true;

                    if (key.equals(GUESSES)){

                        myAnimalQuizFragment.modifyAnimalGuessRows(sharedPreferences);
                        myAnimalQuizFragment.resetAnimalQuiz();

                    }else if (key.equals(ANIMALS_TYPE)){

                        Set<String> animalTypes = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(ANIMALS_TYPE,null);

                        if (animalTypes != null && animalTypes.size() > 0){

                            myAnimalQuizFragment.modifyTypeofAnimals(sharedPreferences);
                            myAnimalQuizFragment.resetAnimalQuiz();
                        }else {

                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                            animalTypes.add(getString(R.string.default_animal_type));
                            editor.putStringSet(ANIMALS_TYPE, animalTypes);      // here we provided default value also.......
                            editor.apply();

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.default_animalType_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }else if (key.equals(QUIZ_FONT)){

                        myAnimalQuizFragment.modifyQuizFont(sharedPreferences);
                        myAnimalQuizFragment.resetAnimalQuiz();

                    }else if (key.equals(QUIZ_BACKGROUND_COLOR)){

                        myAnimalQuizFragment.modifyBackgroundColor(sharedPreferences);
                        myAnimalQuizFragment.resetAnimalQuiz();
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.toast_message , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            };

    public void showDialog(){

        ExampleDialog exampleDialog = new ExampleDialog();
        exampleDialog.setCancelable(false);
        exampleDialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"Animal_Quiz_Result");

    }    
}
```

### Here is the MainActivityFragment.java class

```
import android.animation.Animator;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.content.res.AssetManager;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewAnimationUtils;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.security.SecureRandom;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Set;


public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final int NUMBER_OF_ANIMALS_INCLUDED_IN_QUIZ = 10;

    private List<String> allAnimalsNameList;
    private List<String> animalNamesQuizList;
    private Set<String> animalTypesInQuiz;
    private String correctAnimalsAnswer;
    public static int numberOfAllGuesses;
    private int numberOfAnimalGuessRows;
    private int numberOfRightAnswers;
    private SecureRandom secureRandomNumber;
    private Handler handler;
    private Animation wrongAnswerAnimation;

    private LinearLayout animalQuizLinearLayout;
    private TextView txtQuestionNumber;
    private ImageView imgAnimal;
    private LinearLayout[] rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz;
    private TextView txtAnswer;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        allAnimalsNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        animalNamesQuizList = new ArrayList<>();
        secureRandomNumber = new SecureRandom();
        handler = new Handler();

        wrongAnswerAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.wrong_animation);
        wrongAnswerAnimation.setRepeatCount(1);

        animalQuizLinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.animalQuizLinearLayout);
        txtQuestionNumber = view.findViewById(R.id.txtQuestionNumber);
        imgAnimal = view.findViewById(R.id.imgAnimal);
        rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz = new LinearLayout[3];
        rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz[0] = view.findViewById(R.id.firstRowLinearLayout);
        rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz[1] = view.findViewById(R.id.secondRowLinearLayout);
        rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz[2] = view.findViewById(R.id.thirdRowLinearLayout);
        txtAnswer = view.findViewById(R.id.txtAnswer);

        for (LinearLayout row : rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz) {

            for (int column = 0; column < row.getChildCount(); column++) {

                Button btnGuess = (Button) row.getChildAt(column);
                btnGuess.setOnClickListener(btnGuessListener);
                btnGuess.setTextSize(24);
            }
        }

        txtQuestionNumber.setText(getString(R.string.question_text, 1, NUMBER_OF_ANIMALS_INCLUDED_IN_QUIZ));

        // getString is extends fragment...........


        return view;
    }

    private View.OnClickListener btnGuessListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Button btnGuess = ((Button) view);
            String guessValue = btnGuess.getText().toString();
            String answerValue = getTheExactAnimalName(correctAnimalsAnswer);
            ++numberOfAllGuesses;

            if (guessValue.equals(answerValue)) {

                ++numberOfRightAnswers;

                txtAnswer.setText(answerValue + " ! " + " RIGHT");

                disableQuizGuessButton();

                if (numberOfRightAnswers == NUMBER_OF_ANIMALS_INCLUDED_IN_QUIZ) {

                    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
                    mainActivity.showDialog();

                } else {
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            animateAnimalQuiz(true);
                        }
                    }, 1000); //1000 milliseconds for 1 second delay.......
                }

            } else {
                imgAnimal.startAnimation(wrongAnswerAnimation);
                txtAnswer.setText(R.string.wrong_answer_message);
                btnGuess.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }
    };

    public static String getTheExactAnimalName(String animalName) {

        return animalName.substring(animalName.indexOf('-') + 1).replace('_', ' ');

    }// this method changes the actual name of image for example removes or starts after tame_animal- through index of method
    //  and after that removes _ between the names of animals...........

    private void disableQuizGuessButton() {

        for (int row = 0; row < numberOfAnimalGuessRows; row++) {

            LinearLayout guessRowLinearLayout = rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz[row];

            for (int buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < guessRowLinearLayout.getChildCount(); buttonIndex++) {

                guessRowLinearLayout.getChildAt(buttonIndex).setEnabled(false);

            }

        }
    }

    public void resetAnimalQuiz() {

        AssetManager assets = getActivity().getAssets();
        allAnimalsNameList.clear();

        try {

            for (String animalType : animalTypesInQuiz) {

                String[] animalImagePathsInQuiz = assets.list(animalType);

                for (String animalImagePathInQuiz : animalImagePathsInQuiz) {

                    allAnimalsNameList.add(animalImagePathInQuiz.replace(".png", ""));
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("AnimalQuiz", "Error", e);
        }

        numberOfRightAnswers = 0;       // this variable holds the right guesses must be 0 because we reset the game.
        numberOfAllGuesses = 0;         // this variable holds no. of all guesses whether it is right or wrong have to be 0.
        animalNamesQuizList.clear();    // this variable holds randomly generated quiz paths must be 0 to generate new paths......

        int counter = 1;
        int numberOfAvailableAnimal = allAnimalsNameList.size();// this variable holds number of available animals or the size or length of paths

        while (counter <= NUMBER_OF_ANIMALS_INCLUDED_IN_QUIZ) {

            int randomIndex = secureRandomNumber.nextInt(numberOfAvailableAnimal);

            String animalImageName = allAnimalsNameList.get(randomIndex);

            if (!animalNamesQuizList.contains(animalImageName)) {

                animalNamesQuizList.add(animalImageName);
                ++counter;

            }
        }

        showNextAnimal();

    }

    private void animateAnimalQuiz(boolean animateOutAnimalImage) {

        if (numberOfRightAnswers == 0) {

            return;
        }

        int xTopLeft = 0;
        int yTopLeft = 0;

        int xBottomRight = animalQuizLinearLayout.getLeft() + animalQuizLinearLayout.getRight();
        int yBottomRight = animalQuizLinearLayout.getTop() + animalQuizLinearLayout.getBottom();

        //Here is max value for radius
        int radius = Math.max(animalQuizLinearLayout.getWidth(), animalQuizLinearLayout.getHeight());

        Animator animator;

        if (animateOutAnimalImage) {

            animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(animalQuizLinearLayout, xBottomRight, yBottomRight, radius, 0);

            animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

                    showNextAnimal();

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });

        } else {
            animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(animalQuizLinearLayout, xTopLeft, yTopLeft, 0, radius);
        }

        animator.setDuration(700);
        animator.start();

    }

    private void showNextAnimal() {

        String nextAnimalImageName = animalNamesQuizList.remove(0);
        correctAnimalsAnswer = nextAnimalImageName;
        txtAnswer.setText("");

        txtQuestionNumber.setText(getString(R.string.question_text, (numberOfRightAnswers + 1), NUMBER_OF_ANIMALS_INCLUDED_IN_QUIZ));

        String animalType = nextAnimalImageName.substring(0, nextAnimalImageName.indexOf("-"));  // it holds the animal type whether it is
        // Tame animal or Wild Animal
        AssetManager assets = getActivity().getAssets();

        try (InputStream stream = assets.open(animalType + "/" + nextAnimalImageName + ".png")) {

            Drawable animalImage = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, nextAnimalImageName);
            imgAnimal.setImageDrawable(animalImage);

            animateAnimalQuiz(false);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("AnimalQuiz", "There is an Error Getting" + nextAnimalImageName, e);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(allAnimalsNameList);    // this method is a predefined method in java which helps to shuffle the list of data

        int correctAnimalNameIndex = allAnimalsNameList.indexOf(correctAnimalsAnswer);
        String correctAnimalName = allAnimalsNameList.remove(correctAnimalNameIndex);
        allAnimalsNameList.add(correctAnimalName);

        for (int row = 0; row < numberOfAnimalGuessRows; row++) {

            for (int column = 0; column < rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz[row].getChildCount(); column++) {

                Button btnGuess = (Button) rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz[row].getChildAt(column);
                btnGuess.setEnabled(true);

                String animalImageName = allAnimalsNameList.get((row * 2) + column);
                btnGuess.setText(getTheExactAnimalName(animalImageName));

            }

        }

        int row = secureRandomNumber.nextInt(numberOfAnimalGuessRows);
        int column = secureRandomNumber.nextInt(2);
        LinearLayout randomRow = rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz[row];
        String correctAnimalImageName = getTheExactAnimalName(correctAnimalsAnswer);
        ((Button) randomRow.getChildAt(column)).setText(correctAnimalImageName);

    }

    public void modifyAnimalGuessRows(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences){

        final String NUMBER_OF_GUESS_OPTION = sharedPreferences.getString(GUESSES,null);
        numberOfAnimalGuessRows = Integer.parseInt(NUMBER_OF_GUESS_OPTION)/2;

        for (LinearLayout horizontalLinearLayout : rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz){

            horizontalLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        for (int row = 0; row < numberOfAnimalGuessRows; row++){

            rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz[row].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    }

    public void modifyTypeofAnimals(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences){

        animalTypesInQuiz = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(ANIMALS_TYPE,null);

    }

    public void modifyQuizFont(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences){

        String fontStringValue = sharedPreferences.getString(QUIZ_FONT,null);

        switch (fontStringValue){

            case "Chunkfive.otf":
                for (LinearLayout row : rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz){

                    for (int column = 0; column < row.getChildCount(); column++) {

                        Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(column);
                        button.setTypeface(chunkFive);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "Azkia demo.otf":
                for (LinearLayout row : rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz){

                    for (int column = 0; column < row.getChildCount(); column++) {

                        Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(column);
                        button.setTypeface(azkiaDemo);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "FontleroyBrown.otf":
                for (LinearLayout row : rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz){

                    for (int column = 0; column < row.getChildCount(); column++) {

                        Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(column);
                        button.setTypeface(fontleroyBrown);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "Haunted Eyes.otf":
                for (LinearLayout row : rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz){

                    for (int column = 0; column < row.getChildCount(); column++) {

                        Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(column);
                        button.setTypeface(hauntedEyes);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "Knight Brush Demo.otf":
                for (LinearLayout row : rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz){

                    for (int column = 0; column < row.getChildCount(); column++) {

                        Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(column);
                        button.setTypeface(knightBrushDemo);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "Wonderbar Demo.otf":
                for (LinearLayout row : rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz){

                    for (int column = 0; column < row.getChildCount(); column++) {

                        Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(column);
                        button.setTypeface(wonderbarDemo);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public void modifyBackgroundColor(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences){

        String backgroundColor = sharedPreferences.getString(QUIZ_BACKGROUND_COLOR,null);

        switch (backgroundColor){

            case "White":
                animalQuizLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                for (LinearLayout row : rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz){

                    for (int column = 0; column < row.getChildCount(); column++){

                        Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(column);
                        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(34,167,240));
                        button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    }

                }
                txtQuestionNumber.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                txtAnswer.setTextColor(Color.rgb(34,167,240));
                break;

            case "Black":
                animalQuizLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                for (LinearLayout row : rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz){

                    for (int column = 0; column < row.getChildCount(); column++){

                        Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(column);
                        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(247,202,24));
                        button.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                    }

                }
                txtQuestionNumber.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                txtAnswer.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                break;

            case "Green":
                animalQuizLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(38,166,91));
                for (LinearLayout row : rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz){

                    for (int column = 0; column < row.getChildCount(); column++){

                        Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(column);
                        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(34,167,240));
                        button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    }

                }
                txtQuestionNumber.setTextColor(Color.rgb(247,202,24));
                txtAnswer.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                break;

            case "Yellow":
                animalQuizLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(247,202,24));
                for (LinearLayout row : rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz){

                    for (int column = 0; column < row.getChildCount(); column++){

                        Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(column);
                        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                        button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    }

                }
                txtQuestionNumber.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                txtAnswer.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                break;

            case "Red":
                animalQuizLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(240,52,52));
                for (LinearLayout row : rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz){

                    for (int column = 0; column < row.getChildCount(); column++){

                        Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(column);
                        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(34,167,240));
                        button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    }

                }
                txtQuestionNumber.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                txtAnswer.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                break;

            case "Blue":
                animalQuizLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(34,167,240));
                for (LinearLayout row : rowsOfGuessButtonsInAnimalQuiz){

                    for (int column = 0; column < row.getChildCount(); column++){

                        Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(column);
                        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(240,52,52));
                        button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    }

                }
                txtQuestionNumber.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                txtAnswer.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                break;


        }
    }
}
```

### Here is the ExampleDialog.java class

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

import static com.example.narayanmaity.app61animal_quiz.MainActivityFragment.numberOfAllGuesses;

/**
 * Created by Narayan Maity on 12/14/2017.
 */

public class ExampleDialog extends DialogFragment {

    MainActivityFragment myAnimalQuizFragment;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.results_string_value, numberOfAllGuesses,
                (1000 / (double) numberOfAllGuesses)));

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.result_animal_quiz, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                myAnimalQuizFragment.resetAnimalQuiz();
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Identify the error, where it is occurring and show that portion of code only.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line.Remove the line below from your code

```
 MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
                mainActivity.showDialog();
```

You never ever create an Activity's instance with new operator. Its android Component class it initializes automatically with `Intent` . All Activities in android must go through a lifecycle so that they have a valid context attached to them. Read [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

The solution for this problem.

```
 if(getActivity()!=null){
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).showDialog()
    }
```

For your new problem which you mentioned in comments.
You never assign **myAnimalQuizFragment**  so it will give you  `NullPointerException` anyway . Access it from your MainActivity.

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).myAnimalQuizFragment.resetAnimalQuiz();
```

Make myAnimalQuizFragment as public in MainActivity.

Comment: Thanks @ADM  its solved but after dialog appears when i click reset quiz which is in the dialog screen the application crashes ...... i think ther was the problem in ExampleDialog.java class can u plz show me my mistake

Comment: See updated answer . Accept and upvote the answer it it helped you anyway. Thx

Comment: hey @ADM now i getting error when changing settings several or shared preferences it shows me this error -------------( Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getAssets()' on a null object reference)

Comment: the problem shows in MainActivityFragment.java  ----- resetAnimalQuiz method --------------- AssetManager assets = getActivity().getAssets(); In this section

Comment: Anyway .. it's null pointer exception . Debug your code and find out why you getting null ..